# Access with fetch on a long loading API?

Tags: javascript, php, cors

i tried to fetch with plain JS on a plain PHP REST-API which I wrote.
Problem:
The PHP REST-API have a slightly high loading time because of chance/probability calculations.

So what I tried to access from one Web-Server to an outher is to manipulate the CORS-Protocoll over the headers.

JS Code:

```
async function getData() {
        // Default options are marked with *
        //const newURL = "http://" + host + pathname + "/Server" + search;
        const newURL = "MY_DOM_1/" + search;
        console.log(newURL);
        const response = await fetch(newURL, {
          method: "GET",
          mode: "cors",
          cache: "no-cache",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "MY_DOM_1/",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Content-Type": "application/JSON"
          },
          redirect: "follow",
          referrerPolicy: "no-referrer"
        });
        return await response.json();
      }
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type:application/JSON");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: MY_DOM_2");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: MY_DOM_2");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
?>
```

Didn't work...

Then I added the .htaccess on both servers and let them referenced on each other but it won't work.

Error:

```
Access to fetch at 'MY_DOM_1/?1' from origin 'MY_DOM_2'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
getData.js:7

GET MY_DOM_1/?1 net::ERR_FAILED
getData @ getData.js:7
frame @ loadscreen.js:43
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ loadscreen.js:38
getData.js:7   
    
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getData (getData.js:7:26)
    at frame (loadscreen.js:43:12)
getData @ getData.js:7
frame @ loadscreen.js:43
await in frame (async)
frame @ loadscreen.js:43
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ loadscreen.js:38
console.log(data);
VM556:1 Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getData (MY_DOM_2/tools/js/getData.js:7:26)
  …}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getData (MY_DOM_2/tools/js/getData.js:7:26)
    at frame (MY_DOM_2/tools/js/loadscreen.js:43:12)
```

Access actually works. I tested it by disabling the calculations on the PHP server. But as soon as I let you run through the original calculations and it takes longer, he'll have me out of touch again.

Can someone please help me with this? Unfortunately, I don't think so in relation to fatchen with a long waiting time.

Comment: You don't need to sent the content-type header twice! Also you aren't even sending any JSON data so it makes no sense to use it at all

Comment: And all those Access-Control headers are _response_ headers that the _server_ needs to send. The client side cannot control the CORS settings- if it could, CORS would be completely pointless! You seem to be doing a lot of guessing. Read  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and improve your understanding of CORS, what it does, why it exists, and precisely how it works.

Comment: Ironically, sending those Access-Control headers in your request is exactly what got it blocked (which you can see if you read the error message carefully)!

Comment: Anyway, your question starts off talking about having a performance issue in your php code. But then it moves onto trying to make a CORS request. Did you assume that CORS could somehow solve the performance issue? If so, it's a bit unclear how you reached that conclusion. So what do you really need to solve - the performance issue or the CORS configuration??

Comment: @ADyson I send a JSON I only need help with the connection. The JSON Respons is send after the chance/probability calculations is done.

Comment: The Request works when I use a lower calculation algorythem. But if I turn it back to the original calculation, it will be blocked.

Comment: The reason for the block is given in the error message you showed us, and relates to your erroneous CORS request headers, nothing else. If you are seeing a different problem in a slightly different scenario then you should show us that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the `your_domain.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

here is what I wrote in it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName Your-ServerName
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerAlias www.Your-ServerName
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Your-ServerName
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
                Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT"
                Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
                Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After adding the Headers in the Directory section it works.

Only thing what is I need to fix now is to call the asynchron function simultan to the synchron function. But this is not the topic of this Question.

Thanks to the comments that helped me very much.